# Alignment of images in HTML export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, images

I know that I can align images in html export with the property `#+ATTR_HTML: :align right` upon each image link. But can I set a default for the org-document so that I do not have to add the property to each image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the style used for images by adding custom CSS at the beginning of your document:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style> .figure p {text-align: right;}</style>
```

The above is because images are exported to HTML as a `div` of class `figure`, with a paragraph element `p` containing.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.
Thanks a lot!